# NormalMatrix for OpenGL vertex shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I am using Assimp to import 3d models and which supply me with the tangents and bitangents for its normal maps, however I cannot figure out what the matrix looks like that is used to multiply the tangents and bitangents vectors with in the vertex shader - is it the WorldViewProjection matrix or some other special-purpose "normal matrix"?

UPDATE: my vertex shader

```
const std::string gVertexShader =   "#version 330                                                                                       \n \
                                                                                                                \n \
                                        layout(std140) uniform;                                                 \n \
                                                                                                                \n \
                                        uniform UnifTransform                                                   \n \
                                        {                                                                       \n \
                                            mat4 mWVPMatrix;                                                    \n \
                                            mat4 mWorldMatrix;                                                  \n \
                                            float mTextureTilingFactor;                                         \n \
                                        } Transform;                                                            \n \
                                                                                                                \n \
                                        layout(location = 0) in vec3 vert_position;                                             \n \
                                        layout(location = 1) in vec3 vert_normal;                                                   \n \
                                        layout(location = 2) in vec2 vert_texcoord;                                                 \n \
                                        layout(location = 3) in vec3 vert_tangent;                                                 \n \
                                        layout(location = 4) in vec3 vert_bitangent;                                                 \n \
                                                                                                                \n \
                                        out vec3 frag_position;                                                 \n \
                                        out vec3 frag_normal;                                                   \n \
                                        out vec2 frag_texcoord;                                                 \n \
                                        out vec3 frag_tangent;                                                 \n \
                                        out vec3 frag_bitangent;                                                 \n \
                                                                                                                \n \
                                        void main()                                                                                                 \n \
                                        {                                                                                                                   \n \
                                            gl_Position   = Transform.mWVPMatrix * vec4(vert_position, 1.0);    \n \
                                                                                                                \n \
                                            vec4 position = Transform.mWorldMatrix * vec4(vert_position, 1.0);  \n \
                                            vec4 normal   = Transform.mWorldMatrix * vec4(vert_normal, 0.0);    \n \
                                            vec4 tangent = Transform.mWorldMatrix * vec4(vert_tangent, 0.0);   // correct matrix?   \n \
                                            vec4 bitangent = Transform.mWorldMatrix * vec4(vert_bitangent, 0.0);    \n \
                                                                                                                \n \
                                            frag_position = position.xyz;                                       \n \
                                            frag_normal   = normal.xyz;                                         \n \
                                            frag_tangent   = tangent.xyz;                                         \n \
                                            frag_bitangent = bitangent.xyz;                                         \n \
                                            frag_texcoord = Transform.mTextureTilingFactor * vert_texcoord;     \n \
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TBN (Tangent, Bitangent, Normal) matrix (3x3) is usually used to go from tangent space to object space. You can multiply your normals by this to transform them. Note that normals are directional in nature, so unlike most of the transformation matrices you typically deal with you only need a `vec3` and 3x3 matrix to do this; in my mind, that is what makes this particular matrix "special." Depending on how you use this matrix, you can either transform your light vectors into tangent space, or normal maps into object space.

Generally you do not multiply the Tangent, Bitangent and Normal vectors individually though. They define your vector space basis, and should be left alone. The matrix used to transform into and out of this vector space is derived from these three vectors.

---

You would create the matrix to transform from tangent space to object space by doing this (pseudo code):

```
mat3 (Tangent, Bitangent, Normal);
```

Of course you can use the inverse to go from object space to tangent space. Assimp will probably generate (roughly) orthonormal basis vectors, so the inverse is guaranteed to exist and can be represented as the transpose in this case.

The tangent and bitangent are ***not*** guaranteed to be orthogonal however, as texture sheering may be present and neither one is necessarily perpendicular to the normal either. Some model importing software performs orthogonalization as a post-processing step when outputting the TBN vectors, and most tutorials seem to assume that this relationship ***always*** exists.

Comment: Isnt this matrix used in the fragment shader though? I'm refering to the one in the vertex shader, updated question

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: Not necessarily. You can use it in the fragment shader to transform sampled tangent space normals into object space, this is quite common in deferred shading. You can also use it to transform lighting direction vectors into tangent space in the vertex shader - this is great in forward shading engines because it reduces the complexity of the fragment shader. In all cases, however, you do not need to transform the per-vertex normals, tangents or bitangents.. you *might* alter the TBN matrix to make it do tangent space to view space, however (object space is not usually useful).

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: Can you clarify exactly how you are using the tangent, bitangent and normal vectors in your ***fragment shader***? I am under the impression now from your updated question that you are transforming the sampled tangent space normals into a different vector space (world space in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Tangents and bitangents (also called binormal) follow the same rules as the normals. In fact tangent, binormal and normal form the base of a surface local space, which can be represented by a 3×3 matrix. This space is transformed by the inverse transpose of the modelview matrix (also called the normal matrix).